# Asp.Net Core - Control empty Excel cells to enter information in the database?

Tags: asp.net-core

I use the EPPlus plugin to get information from Excel.The following code works perfectly, but how to control it when it gets an error after it reaches the empty Excel cell?

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> AddExcellHorse(IFormFile ExcelFile)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await ExcelFile.CopyToAsync(stream);

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                var rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;

                for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
                {
                    AddExcelHorse viewModel = new AddExcelHorse()
                    {
                        MicrochipCode = worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString().Trim(),                           
                        EnHorseName = worksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString().Trim(),                           
                        EnFatherHorseName = worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString().Trim(),                           
                        EnMotherHorseName = worksheet.Cells[i, 4].Value.ToString().Trim(),                   
                    };
                    if (viewModel.MicrochipCode != null)
                    {
                        if (!_admin.ChechMicrochip(viewModel.MicrochipCode))
                        {
                            _admin.AddExcelHorse(viewModel);
                        }
                    }                    }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you run into a null reference exception, because the cell value is null, then .ToString() cannot be called.

You could wrap everything in a seperate if-block:

```cs
if(worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != null) 
{
    MicrochipCode = worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString().Trim(), 
}
```

or you use the null propagation:

```cs
MicrochipCode = worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value?.ToString().Trim(), 

//or with default value, if null is not good enough.
MicrochipCode = worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value?.ToString().Trim() ?? String.Empty,
```

Comment: Rejects if the middle of the Excel file is empty or the codes stop?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, I'm afraid